# Distinct columns should have one date per month in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table has columns `Name, EmpName, Date`. For distinct `Name` and `EmpName` values, `Date` should be only one value per month

For example:

```
 Name EmpName Date
 -----------------------
 abc   emp1   3/19/2018
 abc   emp1   3/22/2018  (This record should be rejected)
 xyz   emp2   3/15/2018   valid record
```

I wrote something like this

```
SELECT 
    name, empname,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ORDER BY date DESC)
```

I got stuck writing a `CASE` statement

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Pasting a code block will help others to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by name, empname, year(date), month(date) order by date);
```

However, based on sample data simple aggregation would also work :

```
select name, empname, min(date)
from table t
group by name, empname, year(date), month(date);
```